# Deploy Knowledge Studio dictionary pre-annotator to Natural Language Understanding

Tags: annotations, ibm-watson, watson-knowledge-studio

I'm getting started with `Knowledge Studio` and `Natural Language Understanding`.
I'm able to deploy a machine-learning model to`Natural Language Understanding` and use the API to query it.
I would know if there's a way to deploy only the `pre-annotator`.
I read from [Knowledge Studio's documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/knowledge-studio/publish-ml.html#wks_manlu) that

> You can deploy or export a machine-learning annotator. A dictionary pre-annotator can only be used to pre-annotate documents within Watson Knowledge Studio.

Does exist a workaround to create a model that simply does the job of the `pre-annotator`, i.e. use dictionaries to find entities instead of the machine-learning model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does exist a workaround to create a model that simply does the job of the pre-annotator, i.e. use dictionaries to find entities instead of the machine-learning model?

You may need to explain this better in what you need.

WKS allows you to pre-annotate documents with dictionaries you upload. Once you have created a ML model, you can alternatively use that to annotate your training documents, and then manually correct. As you continue the amount of manual work will reduce after each model iteration.

The assumption is that you are creating a model with a reasonable amount of examples. In your model results, you will want the mention/relations to be outside or close to outside the gray area of the report.

---

The other interpretation of your request I took was you want to create a dictionary based model only. This is possible using the "Rule-Based Model" functionality. You would have to create the parsing rules but you just map what you want to find to the dictionary/rule.

Using this in production though is still limited. You should get a warning when you deploy these kinds of models.

It's slightly better than just a keyword search as you can map items to parts of speech.

---

The last point. The purpose of WKS is to create a machine learning model which will do the work in discovering new terms you haven't seen before. With the rule based engine it can only find what you explicitly tell it to find.

If all you want is just dictionary entries, then you can create a very simple string comparison solution, but you lose the linguistic features.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, for my purpose it's enought the Rule-Based Model.